# Qt breakout game

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qimage

I'm new to Qt and have been trying to get this tutorial to work:
http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/breakoutgame/

Can someone help me out with what my main function would look like?
And where should the images be stored so that they can be referenced with just their names?

Answer (score 4):

Try starting from [this official tutorial](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/tutorial.html). It explains about the `main` function.

And you have the [image viewer](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/widgets-imageviewer.html), which gives a good example of dealing with image files.

Comment: Currently my main is:
`int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Breakout *mainWidget = new Breakout();
    mainWidget->show();

    return app.exec();
}`

Answer (score 2):

If you consider using a Qt/QML based engine, giving you the advantages of cross-platform support and many useful V-Play game components for handling multiple display resolutions & aspect ratios, animations, particles, physics and more, take a look at V-Play (v-play.net).

They also provide you with several demos and tutorials for different skill levels. (http://v-play.net/doc/daily/)

Furthermore you can find a simple BreakOut demo game here: [VZombieBreak](http://v-play.net/doc/daily/demos-vzombiebreak.html)